How to go about replacing arch windows
I currently have an arch window, and its seal seemed to be coming off.
I was wondering how I might go about doing this diy?
How do I find a manufacturer for the glass?
Thanks

Most window/glass shops should be able to custom cut the glass, help with the seals(?).  If you can not fall off a ladder, a nice closer shot picture might help to see what is that black stuff.

As crip659 suggests, you may be able to get a local glass shop to fabricate you an insulated glass unit to replace that.  It's not clear if the muntins are sandwiched between the panes, but they can probably include those too, if you desire.  Are you able to tell if the IGU is integrated into the window frame, or if it's a separate piece?  IDK how DIY-able this is though—glass is heavy.

If that black stuff oozing into the clear glass area is the rubber-like substance between the panes of glass, then there is likely no DIY way to fix it.
Multi-pane windows are used for insulation properties. But atmospheric air between the glass panes contains water vapor, which can condense between the glass panes and make the window foggy.
Window manufacturers place barriers of metal and rubber-like seals, or solid rubber-like substance, between the edges of the glass panes and fill the chamber between the panes with special gasses not containing water that can keep the glass clear.
It looks like your window uses the only-rubber-like substance. Even if you take the window panes apart and reposition the "rubber", you won't have the special gas.
Time to call a window company. You may be fortunate enough that the window may still be manufactured by a national company and may be able to buy an exact replacement that can be popped right back in place. Check for manufacturer markings on the window.
